# Speed up sql query ms sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.Id AS CustomerId,
                C.ZoneId,
                GPC.GeographicalZoneId
FROM   Customers C
       LEFT OUTER JOIN GeographicalZoneZipAndPostalCodes GPC
               ON GPC.ZipAndPostalCodeId = C.PhysicalZipId
```

[image]

Please refer the execution plan and provide me any suggestions to get faster results

Comment: It's as good as it gets

Comment: You might want to put an index on Customers.PhysicalZipId

Comment: Already customers table has an index on PhysicalZipId and I created one more index on ZipAndPostalCodeId column for GeographicalZoneZipAndPostalCodes but still there is no improvement

Comment: can you provide data from the both tables and ddl for your indexes. thanks

Comment: Tablecount of Customers-202181 and GeographicalZoneZipAndPostalCodes-8529
Existing Index on Customer: (PhysicalZipId, Id) and GeographicalZoneZipAndPostalCodes (ZipAndPostalCodeId)

Comment: We need `create table scripts, with indexes`. And you forgot to mention how long does it take now?

Comment: I think the number of records returned is around 200000 ie.,90% of customer table so optimizer choose index scan I guess. Is it possible to improvise the query (consider that the join is left outer join)

Comment: @NewUser, may be you should answer our questions first? Don't you think so?

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri: I am unable to provide DDL scripts since I don't have privileges.

Comment: @NewUser, I was always wondering why someone asks question when he can ask his DBA directly. If you have no priviledges I assume your company has a DBA. Without details it is difficult to answer such questions. One note that you are not filtering so there will be table and index scans.

Comment: @NewUser Consider to remove the `Distinct` and group the `GeographicalZoneZipAndPostalCodes` by `ZipAndPostalCodeId`,  `GeographicalZoneId` before join?

Comment: How about statistics? How recent are they? This sounds like a bad case of stale stats, I don't see why the optimizer would chose to do an index scan to return 90% of the table, instead of doing a full table scan + hash join.

Comment: Statistics are up to date.

Comment: As you're doing a distinct, it's always going to cause an index scan.

Comment: Looks like your schema isn't quite normalised correctly. Which table is causing the duplicate results, and hence the need for the distinct?

Comment: Don't use distinct! Use group by